# Using an inequality on derivative of a function to arrive at an inequality on the function

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Given a function $f \in C^1((0,T])$ for some $T>0$ , satisfying inequality
\begin{equation}
  |f'(t)| \leq \frac{C}{t} \text{ for some }C>0
\end{equation}
I need to prove that 
\begin{equation}
  |f(t)| \leq C'\log\Big(1+\frac{1}{t}\Big) \text{ for some }C'>0.
\end{equation}
My try is as follows
\begin{align}
|f(t)|-|f(T)| &\leq |f(T)-f(t)| \\
& = \Big| \int_{t}^{T}f'(t)dt \Big| \\
& \leq \int_{t}^{T} \frac{C}{t}dt  \\
& = C\log\Big(\frac{T}{t}\Big)
\end{align}
This gives 
\begin{equation}
  |f(t)| \leq C''+C\log\Big(\frac{1}{t}\Big) \text{ where }C''=|f(T)|+C\log(T).
\end{equation}
Taking $C'=max\{C'',C\}$
\begin{equation}
  |f(t)| \leq C'\Big\{1+\log\Big(\frac{1}{t}    \Big)\Big\}
\end{equation}
which not same as what I need to show.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$1 + \log \frac{1}{t} \le 1 + \log(1 + \frac{1}{t}) \le c \log(1 + \frac{1}{t})$$
for $c = \frac{1}{\log(1 + \frac{1}{T})} + 1$.